# Trouble with MdDialogRef from Angular Material testing angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, automated-tests, karma-jasmine

Would anyone help me please!
I'm trying to test my LoginComponent that uses Angular Material, I already use MdDialogRef on production code and this is my test class so far, where I just want to fill all dependencies to make it run:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {
  MdDialogModule,
  MdDialogRef
} from '@angular/material';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { AppMaterialModule } from 'app/module/app-material.module';
import { CustomDialogModule } from 'app/module/custom-modal/custom-dialog.module';

fdescribe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MdDialogModule,
        AppMaterialModule,
        CustomDialogModule
      ],
      providers: [
        MdDialogRef
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

and I keep getting this error: `Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for MdDialogRef: (?, ?).`

Any helps? Thanks!

Comment: This is cause your mockModule is not the same. If you use a dialog you atleast set `declarations: [ YourDialog ], entryComponents: [ YourDialog ]`